# TFS CommandLine: History entries for pending server changes

Tags: command-line, tfs

I would like to query from the command line the list of changesets and their description which haven't been downloaded yet to my workspace.

I know I can use

```
tf.exe vc history /recursive <path to workspace>
```

to get the complete history, but how can I limit this to only those that haven't been downloaded yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To view the history information that hasn't been downloaded, you want to build a query that shows all items beginning in the version that you have (eg, "your workspace version") and ending at the latest version ("tip").

[You can use the `/version` option to `history`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/history-command?view=vsts), and specify a version to begin showing history and a version to stop showing.

For ["versionspecs"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands?view=vsts), you can use `W` which denotes your workspace version, and `T` which denotes tip (or the latest version).

```
tf vc history <path> /recursive /version:W~T
```